# How would I form this function using the indicies and dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
      NDP_INDEX = 0
      GREEN_INDEX = 1
      LIBERAL_INDEX = 2
      CPC_INDEX = 3
```

Let's say there is a constant

```
      PARTY_INDICES = [NDP_INDEX, GREEN_INDEX, LIBERAL_INDEX, CPC_INDEX]
      INDEX_TO_NAME = {NDP_INDEX: 'NDP', GREEN_INDEX: 'GREEN', LIBERAL_INDEX:'LIBERAL'
                       CPC_INDEX: 'CPC'}
      NAME_TO_INDEX = {'NDP':NDP_INDEX, 'GREEN':GREEN_INDEX, 'LIBERAL':LIBERAL_INDEX,
                        'CPC':CPC_INDEX}


def voting_plurality(votes):

    '''(list of str) -> (list of int)
```

The parameter is a list of single-candidate ballots for a single riding.

In Plurality Voting, the party that receives the most votes wins the seat. We have      provided the header and docstring for this function in the starter code.

Return a list of int where the element is a four-element list that contains the number of ballots for each party. The order of the list elements corresponds to the order of the parties in PARTY_INDICES.

```
    >>>voting_plurality(['GREEN', 'GREEN', 'NDP', 'GREEN', 'CPC'])
    [1,3,0,1]
    '''

    party_list = [0, 0, 0, 0]
    #These Gaps need filled out


    return party_list
```

Using no imported program such as enumerate or lambda or such and using the dictionary INDEX_TO_NAME and NAME_TO_INDEX, I need an output of [1,3,0,1] and output is [1,3,0,1] is because There are 3 'GREEN' votes and 'GREEN' is second on the index of PARTY_INDICES, there are 1 'NDP' vote and 'NDP' is first on the index of PARTY_INDICES, there are no 'Liberal' vote and 'Liberal' is third on the index of PARTY_INDICES and there are 1 'CPC' vote and 'CPC' is last on the index of PARTY_INDICES. 
party_list is created and it is used to count the number of votes according to the index of PARTY_INDICES.

Output needs to be [1,3,0,1], I hope this made more sense to people. Please help out. Thank you

Comment: No CAPS, feels like you ARE SHOUTING AT SOMEONE.

Comment: It also shows how desperate I am lol. Please and thank you.

Comment: If you really want help with this, meet people half-way by making sure your code is *reproducible*: people can't run the code you've posted easily because a) some variables like `NDP_INDEX` aren't defined and b) the bits people would need to run are broken up into a bunch of different sections.

Comment: What do you mean?? What I need help with is the indexing NAME_TO_INDEX according to PARTY_INDICES and raise counts of party_list by 1 according to index of PARTY_INDICES, this will take no time for someone who is an expert and I am pretty sure I am at the half way level.

Comment: To be quite honest I can't figure out what you are trying to do or what your problem is. Some things are just whacked like "I used INDEX_TO_NAME too many times." Huh? How can you use it too many times? Try to simplify the problem so you are able to explain it.

Comment: @user1896642: What I mean is that if I wanted to try to solve this problem, I'd want a nice single section of code that I could copy into my editor, so I could start working on the actual problem. People don't want to fiddle around adding lines like `NPD_INDEX = 0` to try and get the code to actually run.

Comment: @Marius I have fixed the code, tell me if there is anything more to add, I need this code to work on other codes, I am desperate, please save a person out, and help if possible. Thank you

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: if this was a test problem where I wasn't allowed to use INDEX_TO_NAME without inverting. How would I do this with using INDEX_TO_NAME.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: Nevermind I was dumb, then could you please help create a result [1,3,0,1] with using any of the two dictionary then??

Comment: No, because I still haven't got a clue what you are doing or where the problem is. And don't tell me in the comments. Edit, clarify and simplify the question until you have gotten to the core of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I think this should work

```
def voting_plurality(votes):
    party_list = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    for i in range(len(votes)):
        if votes[i] in NAME_TO_INDEX:
            party_list[NAME_TO_INDEX[votes[i]]] += 1

    return(INDEX_TO_NAME[index_to_max(party_list)], party_list)
```

Comment: Thank you Clukester, this was what I was looking for